# Minecraft server crashing questions

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Shouldn't questions about minecraft servers crashing be flagged. They pop up all over the recent questions and usually never have an answer. They are too broad and there are countless different possibilities as to what could be happening and how to fix it. All of these questions are just downvoted, and marked as duplicates.

Here is an example of one of these questions.
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/263441/my-minecarft-keeps-crashing-and-i-dont-know-why

Comment: Your example is a question about Minecraft (not MC Server as you said on this post), and was marked as duplicate three times. I consider mark-as-duplicates as answers as the answers are on those links.

Comment: Please read the meta I've linked.